# How do I specify PWA Storage URL?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have two PWAs in individual repositories on my GitHub account (e.g., https://github.com/1John419/pwa01 and https://github.com/1John419/pwa02). The apps are installed from their respective GitHub Pages (e.g., https://1john419.github.io/pwa01/ and https://1john419.github.io/pwa02/).

The problem is the Local Storage and Cache Storage for both apps are pointing to the domain URL (https://1john419.github.io/) rather than the app URL (https://1john419.github.io/pwa01 and https://1john419.github.io/pwa01).

As a result, even though each app's sw.js is only caching its respecting data, DevTools is indicating that each app contains all caches from the domain URL. The service workers are pointing to the app URL, but the Local Storage and Cache Storage are pointing to the domain URL.

When either app is updated, files with common names appear to be overwritten (despite being in uniquely name caches).

Is there a way to make the storage URL point to the app URL rather than the domain URL? If not, what solution would you suggest to keep the apps caches separate?

Update: PWA repos have now been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found. If you know of a better way, post another answer.

In short: No there is no way to specify PWA Storage URL. Browsers use the [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) as the storage URL.

In order to have a unique storage URL for each app, each app needs to be in its own domain or subdomain.

The best solution I found was to purchase a domain and setup a subdomain for each app. I found these resources very useful:

- [Mike Conrad](https://mjconrad.com/blog/serve-your-githubio-site-from-a-subdomain-using-google-domains)
- [Trent Yang](https://trentyang.com/how-to-setup-google-domain-for-github-pages/)
- [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider)

Using this approach, each app has its own storage URL and the apps don't step on each other any more.